# INSERT INTO inserting 0 rows

Tags: postgresql, insert-into

In my Postgresql database, I'm trying to get the coordinates (lat, lon) from a table planet_osm_nodes, where the ids are equal to those in edges2, and insert these into two columns in edges2. Unfortunately, when I run this command:

```
INSERT INTO edges2(node1lat, node1lon) SELECT lat, lon 
FROM edges LEFT OUTER JOIN planet_osm_nodes ON (edges.node1 = 
planet_osm_nodes.id)
```

I get

```
INSERT 0 355466
Query returned successfully in 2 secs 875 msec.
```

and no values have been inserted into my table edges2.

However, when I only run the select command:

```
SELECT lat, lon FROM edges LEFT OUTER JOIN planet_osm_nodes ON (edges.node1 = planet_osm_nodes.id)
```

it returns the columns and data I would like to insert.

Lat and lon are integers, as are the columns that I would like to insert them in, so I have no idea why this doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `INSERT 0 355466` means 355466 rows **have** been inserted

Comment: Did you find any resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that may be happening:

- You already have inserted the data (try to check it)
- You are not commiting the transaction
- You are connected with read-only mode

Comment: I checked all three of those things, but the data is not yet in the table, I am sure I am committing the transaction, and I have permissions to INSERT.

Comment: Can you do a simple insert, with 2 casual values? Does it work?